# RemoveFromSuperview not working on iAd Banner

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iad

`adBannerView.removeFromSuperview()` isn't working on my scene - when you press a button the ad should disappear but it doesn't.

if i print the adBannerView from inside the button pressed block it prints

```
<ADBannerView: 0x15e54b910; frame = (0 0; 414 50); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17024cfc0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x170234640>>
```

so hidden = yes, but it is still shown?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you're triggering the method on the main thread, try this:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
         adBannerView.removeFromSuperview()
})
```